# Encrypt with PGP and Decrypt with GPG

Tags: unix

I've got a situation where the source system has PGP installed, and they can only encrypt the file with PGP tool, and Target System has GPG installed, and we can decrypt only using GPG. is is possible to accomplish this functionality ?

Comment: It should work. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

The thing with encrypting is the encryption algorithm you're using. These algorithms are published and documented - and that means anyone can write code to implement it.

PGP is a piece of software written to implement a crypto algorithm. GPG is the Gnu implementation of the same.

So there's no reason to think this wouldn't work - as long as you use an algorithm that both products support. I believe GPG has more options than PGP.

From:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Privacy_Guard

> As of versions 2.0.26 and 1.4.18, GnuPG supports the following algorithms:
>
> Pubkey: RSA, ElGamal, DSA
>
> Cipher: IDEA (from 1.4.13/2.0.20), 3DES, CAST5, Blowfish, AES-128, AES-192,
>
> AES-256, Twofish, Camellia-128, Camellia-192, Camellia-256 (from 1.4.10/2.0.12)

So as long as your encrypting application uses one of these it should work fine. (`RSA` is probably a pretty good bet.)

Comment: GPG is compatible with PGP "by design". But theoretically your assumption is wrong - the same algorithm can be implemented in different ways from file format's viewpoint and implementations can be incompatible for any small difference.